# Meaning of "optional" for 1-st argument of .call method

Tags: javascript

I have tweaked a Javascript Ninja book's code example (listing 6.9) a bit to make it even shorter. This code snippet is about adding a forEach method to Array.prototype (I renamed it fooEach to avoid confusion). Now the question: Why do we need to pass (context || null) as the first parameter (null in the code example)? Function.call method has its first argument -- the context -- optional, so why is it a must to pass the context as the first parameter in this case?

```
if (!Array.prototype.fooEach) {                                
    Array.prototype.fooEach = function(callback, context) {      
        for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
            callback.call(context || null, this[i], i, this);       
        }
    };
}
["a", "b", "c"].fooEach(function(value, index, array) {        
    console.log(value + " is in position " + index + " out of " + (array.length - 1));
});
```

Comment: it sets the `this` inside of the function.

Comment: @DanielA.White — And why is `null` better than `undefined` or `0`?

Comment: @DanielA.White: The OP asks why they pass `context || null` rather than just `context`. This deserves an explanation, not just closing.

Comment: Seeing that the question was closed as a duplicate (why?), I cannot post an answer. The first argument is "optional" in the sense that if you do not have any value to pass to it, pass `null` or `undefined`. JavaScript has no concept of keyword arguments and due to the types of the other arguments, it's not possible to figure out if the first argument has been skipped.

Comment: Thanks @Blender! This was exactly my confusion. I though "optional" means "may not be there", and obviously was puzzled how the call method can figure out if we pass this first argument to it or not.

Comment: Blender's got it right.

Answer (score 1):

> Function.call method has its first argument -- the context -- optional, so why is it a must to pass the context as the first parameter in this case?

Because `.call()` is a variadic function; it accepts an unknown number of arguments, so any fixed arguments (or arguments with different semantics from the others) are placed at the front.

Specifying either `undefined` or `null` as the first argument will replace `this` inside the function you're calling with the global object (in [non-strict](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode) mode).

Comment: Thanks! The confusion was about the meaning of "optional" for the 1-st ("context") argument. I assumed it's optional for the coder to put it there or not based on the logic of the code. This assumption brought an even greater puzzle -- how .call knows if the 1-st argument passed to it is a context, or smth else?! Now it's all clear  -- one always has to pass the context value, even if it's null.

Comment: @juniorNinja If there are no arguments, you can just do `.call()` as well; in strict mode it will turn `this` into `undefined` though :)